# Cannot add a placeholder with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Why doesn't my code add a placeholder text to the HTML?

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="EmailAddress" class="emailoctopus-custom-fields" tabindex="100">
```

myEdits.js

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //$('class:emailoctopus-custom-fields').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');
    $('input[type=text].emailoctopus-custom-fields').attr('placeholder','Some New Text');
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_codecanal_plugin_script' );
function add_codecanal_plugin_script() {
    wp_register_script('plugin-script',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myEdits.js',array('jquery')); 
    wp_enqueue_script('plugin-script');

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query finds any html elements? Are you sure this attribute is valid for input fields? If not try 'value="Some new text"''

Comment: @Reporter This value is valid for input fields, since over 10 years now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing the code in plugin's root file you have to change the path of `myEdits.js` file like below:

```
wp_register_script('plugin-script',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/myEdits.js',array('jquery'));
```

It Work's for me.